# Is there a way to cast integers to bytes, knowing these ints are in range of bytes. Using SSE?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, sse, sse4

In an xmm register I have 3 integers with values less than 256. I want to cast these to bytes, and save them to memory. I don't know how to approach it.
I was thinking about getting those numbers from `xmm1` and saving them to `eax`, then moving the lowest bytes to memory, but I am not sure how to get integers from an xmm register. I can get only element at 0th position, but how to move the rest?
There exists a perfect instruction that would work for me `VPMOVDB`, but I can't use it on my processor. Is there some alternative for it?

Comment: Is it okay if one additional byte past the end is written?  What instruction set extensions are you permitted to use?

Comment: I can use up to SS4.1 and now that I think I can handle one additional byte.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of related questions recently (starting with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70636962/multiplying-and-adding-float-numbers). I would not say that your questions are bad on their own, but you should really try to optimize the whole problem -- e.g., try to avoid the entire `uint8 -> int32 -> float -> int32 -> uint8` conversion chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use `pshufb` to permute the bytes, followed by `movd` to store the datum:

```
        ; convert dwords in xmm0 into bytes and store into dest
        pshufb  xmm0, xmmword ptr mask
        movd    dword ptr dest, xmm0

        ...
        align   16
mask    db      0, 4, 8, 12, 12 dup (-1)
```

This stores 4 bytes instead of 3, so make sure your code can handle that.  Storing only 3 bytes is also possible, but requires more work:

```
        ; convert dwords in xmm0 into bytes and store into dest
        pshufb  xmm0, xmmword ptr mask
        movd    eax, xmm0
        mov     word ptr dest, ax
        bswap   eax
        mov     byte ptr dest+2, ah

        ...
        align   16
mask    db      0, 4, 8, 12, 12 dup (-1)
```

If this happens more than once, you can load the mask ahead of time to avoid the penalty of repeatedly loading it.

Comment: Another way to store three bytes would be `movd`/`mov ax` + `pextrb` to memory, since we can use SSE4.1.  Reading AH costs extra latency on modern Intel, so instead of bswap you might just `shr eax, 24` and store AL, for only an extra 1 byte of code size.

Comment: Another way to store just three bytes would be to use [`maskmovdqu`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/maskmovdqu) -- but this does not have a very good throughput on most CPUs.